# How to hide outline in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

How to hide outline in Notepad++? The vertical line on the left with pluses and minuses, that allows you to expand/collapse regions. I could not find anything in the settings.

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the view of the folding indicators completely?

Comment: @PaulT. Yes, I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings > Preferences > Editing > Folder Margin Style (set to 'None').